# Maximum Number of box-shadows apply to an element

Tags: html, css, less

I am wondering that more than one box-shadow is possible for HTML Element.And Now I want to explore that the Maximum number of possible box-shadows we can give to an element.Please help me out.

Comment: You can [reproduce sprites with enough box-shadows...](http://www.pixelartcss.com) (preview upper right, CSS bottom left). Fun demo but _don't do this at home kids_ :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many as you want  . But keep in mind that using multiple shadows will increase CPU usage and decrease the performance of your site/application. Also , why would you use more than one ?

To add multiple `box-shadows` to one element, you need to separate with `,` ( comma)  the `box-shadow` values

see below

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 5px 5px #FF1F1F, 15px 0 5px 5px #1100FF, -10px 0 5px 5px #B2FFA6, -10px 30px 5px 10px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is purely dependant on your machine:

The more code (js/styles/etc..) 
- the more resources your browser will consume (RAM, CPU, GPU).

Substract the above from all the other reosurce consuming applicaitons (including OS) and you'll have a very (very) vague estimation